# Google Action - Change timeout of "Free form text"

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I need to implement an action that has to collected anything a user says.
So I use the "Free form text" as "Type" for the slot filling.
This implementation works, however when the user have a pause of 1 second (maybe less of 1 second), google assistant stop to record what user says.
Is it possibile to increment the default timeout of 1 second, for example to 3 or 4 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The platform does not have a way to customize the timeout for any sort of speech input.